# JQuery Simple Addition Issue

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery.Ajax and want to do some addition with the ajax response and predefined variable. My code is as follows -

```
success: function(response)
{
    $('#net_amount').html("$"+(credit+response));
}
```

Assuming 'response' as 10 and 'credit' as 20, it prints 2010. I want it to be 30 (20+30).

What shall I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `+` is used for concatenation in javascript as well as the addition, you need to ensure the type of your variables is numerical, not a string.

Your options are to use `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`. I would suggest the latter as you are dealing with monetary values in your example.

```
success: function(response) {
    $('#net_amount').html("$" + (parseFloat(credit) + parseFloat(response)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you would need to do is parse the value to an Integer first as follows:

`$('#net_amount').html("$" + ( parseInt(credit) + parseInt(response) ));`

Answer (score 0):

The response or credit is being treated as a string. (probably the response).

```
success: function(response)
{
    $('#net_amount').html("$"+(parseInt(credit)+parseInt(response)));
}
```

The above will give you the expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
use parseInt() or parseFloat() its convert into Integer format

E;g:

     var     credit =   '30';
            response=   '20';

     alert(typeof(response)); // string
     alert("++++++++++++"+"$"+(parseInt(credit)+parseInt(response))+"++++++++++++");

if your value as in Integer, then u no need to go for parseInt(),parseFloat()

     var   credit = 30;
          response= 20;

     alert(typeof(response)); // // Integer 
     alert("++++++++++++"+"$"+((credit)+(response))+"++++++++++++");
```

Comment: Least. Readable. Answer. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to multiply the values of credit and response by 1 at the same time you're adding them. This will force JS to treat them as numeric values rather than strings.

```
success: function(response)
{
    $('#net_amount').html("$"+((credit*1.00)+(response*1.00)));
}
```